# Escape quotation with backslash

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am trying to insert data into MySQL, and while doing so, was faced with the error where the input has single quotation, therefore breaking my sql insert string.

This is my line of code

```
                    String visitorSql = "INSERT INTO visitor" + "(encryptedEmail)" + "VALUES ('" + encryptedEmail.replace("'", "\\'")+"')";
```

The syntax error is,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''w+8L8%]/ò“VZ(R?cêíµ–ö\')' at line 1
```

I've encrypted the email for the sake of the privacy. Any other idea how should I code it to escape the quotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace all the single quotes(') with ''(2 single quotes) to escape them.

```
String visitorSql = "INSERT INTO visitor(COLUMN_NM) VALUES ('" + encryptedEmail.replace("'", "''")+"')";
```

Comment: Paste the query formed here.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Oó¶„ßåÞ eHß<.2?@{rTì¶?=@q+ü\')' at line 1